# Populate a Custom Lookup Field in Quote Object from another Custom Object using Trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, quote

Experts,

I had been working on this issue for quite a few days but with no luck and need your help.

Fields on Quote Object:
**1) Approver (Lookup field)**

2) Approval Level (possible values - 1, 2, 3, 4)

3) Owner

Fields on Custom Object ABC (this object is like a table with all users with their 4 levels of approvers):

1) Requester (this field is all the users)

2) Level 1 Approver

3) Level 2 Approver

4) Level 3 Approver

5) Level 4 Approver

I need to populate the "Approver" field in Quote object based on the following criteria:

**If Quote.Owner = ABC.Requester and Quote.Approval_Level = 1, then populate the "Approver" field in Quote Object with the value in "Level 1 Approver" from the ABC object.

and similarly for Approval Level 2 and hence forth..**

I am new to Triggers, but here is my piece of code where I need help:

```
trigger UpdateQuoteApprover on Quote(before insert, before update) 

{

    Set<String> Apprv_Level = new Set<String>();

    Set<id> Ownerid = new Set<id>();

    for (Quote Q : Trigger.new)

    {

        Apprv_Level.add(Approval_Level__c);

        Ownerid.add(Owner.id);

    }

    List myQuer = [Select Level_1_Approver__c, Requester__c from Quote where Requester__c = Ownerid and Approval_Level__c = Apprv_Level];

    for (Quote Q : Trigger.new)

    {

        O.Approver__c = myQuer.Level_1_Approver__c;

    }

}
```

Thanks,

ASZ67

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Believe me when I say that I'm not an expert. You have been trying this from several days, it will be helpful for us if you can post the code that you have written. We can find out what is the issue in the code and resolve it.

Comment: Hi asz67, welcome to SFSE! Your question appears to be asking for other people to write code for you. SFSE is a Q&A forum where we look to help each other by asking and answering questions about real problems or errors with our code. Posting requests to write code for you will get closed. If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am new to the forum and to Triggers as well, and didn't know that code snippet is mandatory because while doing some research i did find posts with only questions and no code and replies for them.
But I will mention the code i have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example. It assumes that Approval_Level__c is a string, if not you will have to modify. Also, it assumes that on the ABC object the Level_x_Approver__c filed name will always maintain the same format

```
trigger UpdateQuoteApprover on Quote(before insert, before update) 

{

    //Set of Owner IDs
    Set<id> Ownerid = new Set<id>();

    for (Quote Q : Trigger.new)

    {

        Ownerid.add(Owner.id);

    }

    //Map to hold OwnerIDs to the appropriate ABC__c records
    Map<ID,ABC__c> approverMap = New Map<ID,ABC__c>();

    for(ABC__c abc : [Select Level_1_Approver__c, Level_2_Approver__c, Level_3_Approver__c, Level_4_Approver__c, Requester__c from ABC__c where Requester__c IN :Ownerid]){
        approverMap.put(abc.Requestor__c,abc__c);
    }

    for (Quote Q : Trigger.new)

    {
        //If we have an ABC record and the Approval_Level__c is not blank
        if(approverMap.containsKey(q.OwnerID) && !string.isBlank(q.Approval_Level__c)){

            //Get the level to get the appropriate field on the ABC Object
            String lvl = string.valueOf(q.Approval_Level__c);

            //Get the value of the appropriate field
            Object app = approverMap.get(q.OwnerID).get('Level_' + lvl + '_Approver__c');

            //Check to ensure not null so we do not get the Parameter 1 cannot be null error
            if(app != null)
                q.Approver__c = (String)app;

        }

    }

}
```

You can also add `if...then...else` block instead of the "dynamic" logic